# Плывет сайт при масштабировании или изменении окна

Tags: html, css, масштабирование

*Заранее извиняюсь за заезженный вопрос.*

Сверстал я горизонтальный `header` для своего сайта с помощью `<ul>, <li>.` Сделав при этом 3 `<li>`. В крайний левый пункт вложил логотип, в средний меню, и в правый номера телефонов.

При масштабировании (ctrl + колесико) или изменении ширины окна браузера, все мое меню плывет как попало и напоминает список (думаю вы поняли).

**Вопрос:** как мне сохранить внешний вид, так чтобы сайт просто масштабировался без смещения и наползания элементов друг на друга (хотя бы до 1024 по ширине)? Как, например, здесь: http://football.ua/

**п.с.** вариант с ограничением размера окна через `'min-width'` не подходит.

Сам сижу на 1600:900 и хочу чтоб  все сохранялось при 1024:768 (просто уменьшалось по масштабу), но у меня плывет даже на 1366:768.

**Появилась мысль:** А если изначально я буду верстать под ширину 1024х
через инструменты разработчика в браузере, решит ли это мою проблему?

Сам сайт: [danyilzborovskyi.000webhostapp.com](http://danyilzborovskyi.000webhostapp.com)

Comment: "Сверстал я горизонтальный header для своего сайта с помощью <ul>, <li>. Сделав при этом 3 <li>. В крайний левый пункт вложил логотип..."
Зачем?

Comment: покажите код, без него вам не помочь

Comment: @РашенБеар а как лучше тогда делать? без добавления в список?

Comment: @kizoso добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - у вас ошибка в коде:

```
<p><li>ул. Верхний Вал, 52<br>
                (м. Контрактовая площаль)</p>
                </li>
```

так теги закрывать нельзя - исправьте:

```
<li>
  <p>
    ул. Верхний Вал, 52<br>
    (м. Контрактовая площаль)
  </p>
</li>
```

2 - после Ul должен идти li, так не правильно:

```
<p><li><a href='tel:+380444259226'>+38 (044) 425 92 26</a></li>
<li><a href='tel:+380665704227'>+38 (066) 570 42 27</a></li></p>
```

Лучше внутри одного li разбейте на p

Comment: поправил, спасибо. Что думаете насчет масштабирования?)

Comment: Загрузите изображения в код, соберите код воедино с помощью функции вставки кода, тогда будет наглядно и можно будет что-то сказать

Comment: я залил, так подойдет: https://danyilzborovskyi.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: Он у вас не адаптивный и не зафиксирован, конечно будет ехать, сделайте ширину например: #pageWrapper {width:1600px;margin:0 auto}

Comment: тоже к этому только что пришел) спасибо огромное, поставил плюс!) а не подскажите еще как можно сделать так, чтоб вся страница (#pageWrapper) была шириной 1600 например, а фон хедера (header) на всю ширину экрана?